# How to extract a last block from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing many blocks like this:

```
==9673== 
==9673== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9673==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9673==   total heap usage: 75,308 allocs, 75,308 frees, 7,099,382 bytes allocated
==9673== 
==9673== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9673== 
==9673== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9673== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
....
....
....
....

==9655== 
==9655== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9655==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9655==   total heap usage: 75,308 allocs, 75,308 frees, 7,099,382 bytes allocated
==9655== 
==9655== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9655== 
==9655== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9655== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

....
....
....

==9699== 
==9699== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9699==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9699==   total heap usage: 75,308 allocs, 75,308 frees, 7,099,382 bytes allocated
==9699== 
==9699== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9699== 
==9699== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9699== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I want to extract the last block starting with line:

```
 ==XXXX== HEAP SUMMARY:
```

So in my example I want to extract only the last bloc:

```
==9699== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9699==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9699==   total heap usage: 75,308 allocs, 75,308 frees, 7,099,382 bytes allocated
==9699== 
==9699== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9699== 
==9699== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9699== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How I can do that with bash?

Comment: [edit] your input to get rid of all the `...`s and make it a concrete, testable example. The text between your blocks is every bit as important as your blocks. For example if there really is a blank line between each block as your example currently implies then all you need is `awk -v RS= '{s=$0} END{print s}' file` and if each block is 8 lines than all you need is `tail -8 file` but idk if either of those is really how your input is formatted or not.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -zoP` and a negative lookahead regex:

```
grep -zoP '==\w{4}== HEAP SUMMARY:(?![\s\S]*==\w{4}== HEAP SUMMARY:)[\s\S]*\z' file

==9699== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9699==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9699==   total heap usage: 75,308 allocs, 75,308 frees, 7,099,382 bytes allocated
==9699==
==9699== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9699==
==9699== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9699== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

- `-z` treats file data as null terminated instead of new line terminated
- `(?![\s\S]*==\w{4}== HEAP SUMMARY:)` is negative lookahead that asserts we don't have another instance of the same in the file below.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy7IZB/7)

Answer (score 2):

if you have `tac`, this might be the easiest

```
$ tac file | awk '1; /==....== HEAP SUMMARY/{exit}' | tac
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
$ sed -n '/HEAP SUMMARY/{:a;/ERROR SUMMARY/bb;N;ba;:b;$p;d}' infile
==9699== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9699==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9699==   total heap usage: 75,308 allocs, 75,308 frees, 7,099,382 bytes allocated
==9699== 
==9699== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9699== 
==9699== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9699== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here is how this works:

```
sed -n '                   # Do not print lines at end of each cycle
    /HEAP SUMMARY/ {       # If line matches "HEAP SUMMARY"
        :a                 # Label to jump back to
        /ERROR SUMMARY/bb  # If line matches "ERROR SUMMARY", jump to :b
        N                  # Append next line to pattern space
        ba                 # Jump to :a
        :b                 # Label to jump forward to
        $p                 # If we are on the last line, print pattern space
        d                  # Delete pattern space
    }
' infile
```

Each time this encounters `HEAP SUMMARY`, it reads all the lines up to the next `ERROR SUMMARY` into the pattern space. Then, it checks if the last line has been reached; if yes, the pattern space gets printed, if not, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the blocks are always 9 lines long, you can simply use `tail`:

```
tail -n9 file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/HEAP SUMMARY:/h;//!H;$!d;x' file
```

When encountering `HEAP SUMMARY:` replace whatever is in the hold space (HS) by the current line. For any other pattern append tha line to the HS. Delete all lines excepting the last, when the pattern space (PS) is swapped with the HS  and the PS is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

If the last line of the file also has the block number, this will get the block number fast (no reading of the whole file to find which number that is):

```
n="$(tail -n1 infile | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Then we can select all lines that have such block number from the end up:

```
tac infile | awk -vn="$n" '!($1~n){exit};1'| tac
```

Answer (score 0):

Using number in front of data as an id /group number:

```
id=$(tail -n1 file | grep -Po '(?<=\=\=)[0-9]*') && grep "$id" file |tail -n+2
```